# Python - S3 Download file using download_fileobj

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, download, boto3

The following function downloads a file from S3 using a progress callback. The code works fine, but when it reaches 100%, it takes a long time to return. The problem gets worse when the file is large. I think that `f.seek(0)` is causing the issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Removing it causes error in some cases.

```
def download(s3_client, s3_object_key):
    meta_data = s3_client.head_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=s3_object_key)
    total_length = int(meta_data.get('ContentLength', 0))
    downloaded = 0

    def progress(chunk):
        nonlocal downloaded
        downloaded += chunk
        done = int(50 * downloaded / total_length)
        sys.stdout.write("\r[%s%s] %%%s " % ('=' * done, ' ' * (50 - done), round(downloaded / total_length * 100, 2)))
        sys.stdout.flush()

    print(f'Downloading {s3_object_key}')

    f = io.BytesIO()
    s3_client.download_fileobj(BUCKET, s3_object_key, f, Callback=progress)
    f.seek(0) # <---- Could be the cause
    print('Done.')
    return f
```

Comment: seek should be O(1) complexity. Have you tried to simplify your snippet and remove callback completely?

Comment: What error does it cause? Maybe try using `download_file()` instead of `download_fileobj()`?

Comment: `download_file` does not allow to keep the obj in memory.